# can you boot from a dynamic disk?

Tags: boot

I'm thinking not, but would just like to check if that is the case for peace of mind. My thinking is the dynamic disk would be one big partitioned and then broken into volumes and you can not boot this way?

Answer (score -1):

No you can not mark  dynamic disk as active partition

Comment: Do you have an authoritative source for this declaration, or are you simply saying that you were _unable_ to mark a dynamic disk as the active partition?

Comment: Source from a book

Comment: Well, then, cite your source.  (Edit your answer; don't put it in a comment.)